# Passing multiple methods into Apex 'rendered' attribute

Tags: renderer, apex

Can I pass a second method into the rendered attribute of the following apex element?

```
        <apex:outputText rendered="{!(firstMethod == true)}">           
            <img class="refresh_btn" src="{!URLFOR($Resource.Images, 'images/icon_refresh.png')}" alt=""/>
        </apex:outputText>
```

Would this work?

```
        <apex:outputText rendered="{!(firstMethod == true)} && {!(secondMethod == true)}">          
            <img class="refresh_btn" src="{!URLFOR($Resource.Images, 'images/icon_refresh.png')}" alt=""/>
        </apex:outputText>
```

So both firstMethod and secondMethod must return true for the element to render.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer...

```
<apex:outputText rendered="{!(firstMethod == true) && (secondMethod == true)}">
```